# AngularJS ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm currently working on a notifications page where the user can recieve a notification out from 4 actions done to his posts:

follow, like, ect.

Each object has a 'concirning' variable which gives the action of what happened.

Though for every action I would like another sentence (obviously)

Currently I have the following but it is a bit messy in my eyes:

```
<div ng-repeat="notification in notifications | orderBy :'created_at':true | limitTo:10" class="list-group-item dash-posts">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img ng-src="{{notification.user.picture}}" max-width="40px" width="50px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <span ng-if="notification.notification.concirning=='comment'"><strong>{{notification.user.name}}</strong> has commented on one of your captures.</span>
                    <span ng-if="notification.notification.concirning=='birdsuggestion'"><strong>{{notification.user.name}}</strong> has given a birdname for your capture! Go check it out!</span>
                    <span ng-if="notification.notification.concirning=='like'"><strong>{{notification.user.name}}</strong> has just liked your capture!</span>
                    <span ng-if="notification.notification.concirning=='follow'"><strong>{{notification.user.name}}</strong> has started following you.</span>
                </div>
                </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The notification consists of 2 objects: 
`notification.user` that preformed the action to trigger the notification
and the notification itself as `notification.notification`

Is there a way for me to clean this out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

In your JS :

```
$scope.message="";
$scope.$watch('notification.notification.concirning', function (value) {
    if (value== "comment") {
        $scope.message="whatever message you want"; 
    }
    //Put conditions for each type of concirning
});
```

In you html :

```
<div class="col-md-11">
     <span ng-if="notification.notification.concirning=='comment'">{{message}}</span>
</div>
```

If your message has html elements/tage read more about `ng-bind-html`

Comment: you probably wanted to put `{{message}}`instead of `$scope.message` in your HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it cleaner with [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch):

```
<div ng-repeat="notification in notifications | orderBy :'created_at':true | limitTo:10" class="list-group-item dash-posts">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <img ng-src="{{notification.user.picture}}" max-width="40px" width="50px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11" ng-switch="notification.notification.concirning">
      <span ng-switch-when="comment"><strong>{{notification.user.name}}</strong> has commented on one of your captures.</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="birdsuggestion"><strong>{{notification.user.name}}</strong> has given a birdname for your capture! Go check it out!</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="like"><strong>{{notification.user.name}}</strong> has just liked your capture!</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="follow"><strong>{{notification.user.name}}</strong> has started following you.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: to be honest, this take the same amount of code to write, so  don't think this is what the OP is looking for

Comment: @Walfrat It's not about amount of code. It could be even more, if you want. But if it's **cleaner** like in this case - then it's what we want. On the other hand, you may think your solution is good, because template is terse.. I will disappoint you: your solution is probably worst of all possible. I would definitely advise against hardcoding HTML code into controller. Original OP's code was way better.

Comment: That code is within the controller, it could be fetched from the server dynamically. This will require to watch for the map of pass to the directive a promise instead of the raw object.

Comment: I understand what it does, but I'm saying this is really-really bad approach for this problem. Doesn't matter if it comes from server or from controller - you moved part of template somewhere else to "simplify" template. But in reality it doesn't make it simpler, but rather makes it harder to maintain and error prone. Again, original OP's code is better.

Comment: This was just a total generic sample as a starting point. You can choose something less generic. Like instead of having the mapping key.template in the controller, you would have it in the directive. And having that in the directive, follow angularJS guidelines.

Comment: Well, this is a problem.. the directive you created, what it does and how it does - this is hardly a recommended way of designing directives. The purpose of directives is not to *hide* parts of HTML and make it harder to reason about how and what gets rendered where (like in your case).

Comment: The purpose is to provide an expressive, declarative way of componentization of the UI (components), or extending behaviour of HTML (like attribute directives). What you did is you simply moved HTML into controller|directives|whereever, it decreased readability of the result. You could also use ngInclude for the same result, but it would still be wrong. I don't think usage of directive like you did is justified in this case. You might think differently, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114318/discussion-between-walfrat-and-dfsq).

Answer (score 0):

The really best and generic way for this is a directive.

Here is a little directive which take 3 params :

- object : value to be used if you use angular templating in the value of the map
- map : a simple key/value object, object can be HTML, if so you can use angular templating in to display data of the object {{object.[...]}}
- key : they key that determine which message display

It's possible there is some cleaner way of doing this like :

- Instead of assing raw map, pass a function so you can handle more complex case if needed
- use attr instead of isolated scope and set the scope to true to inherits from other scope, so you can use everything stored upside. Otherwise you'll need a wrapper object that you will need to refresh if the value within change.
- Use something less generic, define the mapping key/template in the directive, this follow better the angularJS's guidelines. So you would have to define one directive per mapping.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){
    $scope.map = {
        'comment':$sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>{{object.user.name}}</strong> has commented on one of your captures.'),
         'birdsuggestion':$sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>{{object.user.name}}</strong> has given a birdname for your capture! Go check it out!'),
          'like':$sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>{{object.user.name}}</strong> has just liked your capture!'),
          'follow':$sce.trustAsHtml('<strong>{{object.user.name}}</strong> has started following you.')
    };
    $scope.notifications = [{
        user:{name:'foo'},
        notification:{concirning:'comment'}
    }, {
      user:{name:'bar'},
      notification:{concirning:'like'}
    }]
}]).directive('mapMessageToView', function($compile){
   return{
     restrict:'A',
     scope:{
         map:"=",
         key:"=",
        object:"="
     },
     replace:false,
     link:function(scope, element, attr){
         element.html(scope.map[scope.key]);
         $compile(element.contents())(scope);
         scope.$watch('key', function(newValue){
             element.html(scope.map[scope.key]);
             $compile(element.contents())(scope);
         });
     }
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
    <div ng-repeat="notification in notifications">
        <div>
           <span map-message-to-view key="notification.notification.concirning" map="map" object="notification"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```